# Redundant Nginx Location and Rewrite Regular Expression

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a location and rewrite directive pair that works, but there is a redundancy that it seems like I should be able to optimize out.  It takes an external URL like `/css/20141201-styles.css` and delivers `/css/styles.css`.

```
location ~ '^/(css|js)/[0-9]{8}-' {
    rewrite '^/(css|js)/[0-9]{8}-(.*)$' /$1/$2;
}
```

It seems like I'm doing work twice, once in matching, and then again when rewriting. Is there a way to capture the matches in the `location` directive, and then use them in the `rewrite`?

```
location ~ '^/(css|js)/[0-9]{8}-(.*)$' {
    rewrite [something here?] /$1/$2;
}
```

In Apache, it looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/(css|js)/[0-9]{8}-(.*)$ /$1/$2 [NC,L]
```

---

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to [Terra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4347203/terra) for pointing out the `alias` directive! This `location` was already nested in another `location` which applies the `root` directive, so that takes care of the server path.

```
location ~ ^/(css|images|js)/ {
    location ~ '^/(css|js)/[0-9]{8}-(.*)$' {
        alias /$1/$2;
    }
    root /server/path/to/web/root;
}
```

**UPDATE**

This also works, and has fewer lines. The `break` flag on the `rewrite` directive prevents looping of the `server` level, making it [just as performant](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/73342/49814) as the `alias` solution.

```
location ~ ^/(css|images|js)/ {
    rewrite '^/(css|js)/[0-9]{8}-(.*)$' /$1/$2 break;
    root /server/path/to/web/root;
}
```

Comment: Rewrite is always less optimal than root or alias. There's as simple reason: rewrite alters the internal request uri, so it still has to look for a location to match. A location wit a root, alias or dispatch to a backend is final and can be served.

Comment: @Melvyn - Can you point out some documentation for that? I don't quite follow what you're saying, and I'd like to read up on it more in-depth.

Comment: Sure, just look at the documentation for rewrite. Once the rewrite is done, the new uri is once again matched against available locations.

Comment: No, think of a rewrite as a brush and a location as a container. You want all red things in a container and all blue things in another. But you paint all red balloons blue. They don't belong in the container for red items anymore, so you have to look for the container for blue items now. Sorry for the analogy, but it's the simplest way to explain it.

Comment: @Melvyn - Sorry, I removed my question, which provided context for your response. I have another post on Code Review that I've now linked to in my OP. I found the documentation. Your analogy works very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1: Do not create separate location, just move `rewrite` to other one. `location /` for example.

Solution 2:

```
location ~ ^/(css|js)/[0-9]{8}/ {
    alias /server/path/to/web/root/$1/;
}
```

Comment: The `alias` directive looks like *exactly* what I want!

Comment: I created a post on Code Review in reference to this, because I think the scope is too broad for Stack Overflow: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/73342/49814

Comment: And solution three is to symlink the file. ;-)